# Encode URL using Windows Ansi encoding

Tags: c#, .net, url, ftp

There are file on with ALT+0174 symbol ® (registred/reserved)

`http:/ftp.com/longname_®.png_thumbnail.jpg`

I try use

```cs
var pathToFile = "http://ftp.com/longname_®.png_thumbnail.jpg";
Html.Encode(pathToFile);
Html.Raw(Url.Encode(pathToFile));
```

I got 
`http%3a%2f%2fftp.com%2longname_%c2%ae.png_thumbnail.jpg`, note `%C2%AE`.

But valid URL is `http%3a%2f%2fftp.com%2longname_%ae.png_thumbnail.jpg`, note `%AE`.

Why?

Comment: `%AE` is an result of `escape` function
`%C2%AE` is and result of `encodeURI`

Why do you expect `%AE`? It seems that `%C2%AE` is good result since escape method is deprecated.

Comment: AFAIK %c2 represents `Â` (A with top accent) character, the correct encoded URL probably `http%3a%2f%2fftp.com%2flongname_%ae.png_thumbnail.jpg`.

Comment: @tomaso ftp.com response only with _%AE.png. %CA%AE http404

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ input Alt+0174 - Endode - %CA%AE

Comment: Either ftp.com is wrong or you have uploaded the file to the ftp.com using wrong encoding for the file name.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl May be ftp.com but i cant manage ftp.com. With ftp client i see valid name, with ftp.com http client i see url %EA.png and can download. But can publish url on my asp site because get %C2%AE

Comment: So your FTP client can be wrong. Which one do you use?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ftp client in TotalComander

Comment: Try to force UTF-8 in *Connection details > Advanced > Encoding of file names*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Not found it. I see in command list "OPTS UTF8 ON"

Comment: If you upload a file named like `こんにちはЗдравствуйте.txt`, does it preserve its name? - What HTTP URL would ftp.com accept for such file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ____%c7%e4%f0%e0%e2%f1%f2%e2%f3%e9%f2%e5.txt

Comment: So does it preserve the name or not? Can you see `こんにちはЗдравствуйте.txt` in the Total Commander after upload? It does not look like to me.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl in ftp client "_____Здравствуйте.txt" in http "____%c7%e4%f0%e0%e2%f1%f2%e2%f3%e9%f2%e5.txt"

Comment: So the client does not use UTF. Being Ukrainian, it's probably Windows-1251, that's why the Cyrillic is preserved, while Kanji is not. It uses your legacy Ansi encoding most probably. You can also see that there's only one `%XX` per Cyrillic letter, while there would be more, if UTF-8 was used. What does the server respond to `OPTS UTF8 ON`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks. Really ftp on OPTS UTF8 answer 504 Unknown.

Comment: So again, try force UTF-8 in Total Commander: *Net > FTP Connect > New connection > Advanced > Encoding of file names > UTF-8*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Error 504 on OPTS UTF8. In TC if copy file name i have _®.png_thumbnail.jpg and "こんにちはЗдравствуйте.txt"

Comment: Looks good. So what URL does now the ftp.com offer for these files?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a1%e3%81%af%d0%97%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5.txt" and "_%ae.png_thumbnail.jpg"

Comment: Did you re-upload the `_®.png_thumbnail.jpg`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can re-upload. Files was uploads other software i can/must show download link to it.

Comment: So the other software uploads it incorrectly. While you can workaround that by generating URL in Windows-1251 encoding, it will break, once the file contains any character that is not present in the Windows-1251 encoding - Is that what you want?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks. I think yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is uploaded using [Windows-1251 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) used for file name. In Windows-1251, the `®` has code `AE`.

That's wrong in general, you should get the file re-uploaded using UTF-8 encoding.

---

If you cannot get it re-uploaded, you have to implement the URL-encoding using the Windows-1251 text encoding.

There can be easier solution, but this should do:

```
const string filename = "longname_®.png_thumbnail.jpg";

// You can also use Encoding.Default, as that should return Windows-1251 on your machine,
// as you obviously have the 1251 set as the default legacy Ansi encoding.
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(filename);

string encoded = "";
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    char c = (char)bytes[i];
    if (c >= 0x80)
    {
        // URL-encode all characters in range 128-255
        encoded += Uri.HexEscape(c);
    }
    else
    {
        // URL-encode only reserved characters in range 0-127
        encoded += Uri.EscapeDataString(new string(c, 1));
    }
}
```

This will get you `longname_%AE.png_thumbnail.jpg` in `encoded`.